Updating to Ubuntu 24.10 makes Nvidia drivers disappear
I have been using Ubuntu for years, and most recently 24.04 without issues.
After upgrading to 24.10, the Nvidia drivers seem to be disabled,and the "Additional Drivers" in "Software & Updates" is empty ("No additional drivers available").
The system appears to correctly detect the NVIDIA card:
─( sudo lshw -C display                  

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 resolution=1024,768
       resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

and trying the autoinstall believes that everything is just fine:
└─( sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall       
All the available drivers are already installed.


however, I am stuck with a 1024x768 low resolution, and I cannot change it in my System Settings Display pane.
I have also tried to install manually the NVIDIA drivers:
└─( sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-550

and rebooted, but no success either.
I have had similar issues in the past (every new Ubuntu install practically requires the same dance) but the Additional Drivers have always been there.
Does anyone know how to make them appear again?
Or at least configure it so that I can have back my high resolution display.
Thanks!

Is the "restricted" proprietary software checked off under the first tab (Ubuntu sofware) of the software&Updates app?

Yes, that was the first thing I looked at, also I think if it's not checked the tab is disabled.

The issue was the nvidia-driver-550.
Trying to switch window manager (I was on gdm3, thought I'd try lightdm) situation got worse (couldn't even boot into X) but could see a message stating that the 550 driver was "ignoring" my GTX770.
I then decided to clean up everything, and re-install the -470 driver which I knew was good.
This is what solved the problem:
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-550 nvidia-driver-560
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot

I had even downloaded the 470 driver from Nvidia but that turned out to be unnecessary: after reboot (into gdm3) it all worked just fine, and I can select any resolution I want from the System Settings.
"Additional Drivers" still shows "No additional drivers" but that is something I don't much care about at this point.

this helped me, after upgrading to 24.10 my display was 1024x768. I ran your commands and all is fine now

In my article:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1536862/ubuntu-24-10-gp107-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-not-showing-full-resolution-on-the-dvi - I tried the listed steps to remove the NVIDIA driver and I now have full resolution on the DVI port on the GP107 GTX 1050 display card.  That port works great now.  But the Display Port (DP) and the HDMI port do not work at all.  Is there a way to get not just the DVI port but also these other ports to work as well?
