Ubuntu 24.10 GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] not showing full resolution on the DVI port w NVIDIA latest driver and without driver DP and HDMI do not work
The system details for the computer are as follows:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-12-31 11:01:58

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              ASUS All Series
- **Memory:**                                      4.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i3-4170 × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    Software Rendering
- **Disk Capacity:**                               560.1 GB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            1103
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               47
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.11.0-13-generic

These are after removing the nvidia-driver-550 which was causing display resolution issues on the DVI port of the card, which includes three ports (DVI, HDMI, and Display Port (DP).
This was after carefully following the steps in the article Updating to Ubuntu 24.10 makes Nvidia drivers disappear.  I confirmed that sudo lshw -C display showed the card as a GTX 1050 Ti.  After the steps that were taken in Updating to Ubuntu 24.10 makes Nvidia drivers disappear to update the NVIDIA driver and remove it, now I have full display resolution on the DVI port only.  Nothing comes out of the HDMI port or the DP port. The other displays are not even listed.  The current output (after resolving the resolution issue with the DVI port) details are listed as:
stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
stephen@stephen-All-Series:~$ 

No driver is listed there, not the nouveau open source driver and also not the i915 driver mentioned in the article How to find out what graphics driver is installed?.  It makes some sense because I removed the drivers according to the instructions in Updating to Ubuntu 24.10 makes Nvidia drivers disappear to resolve the resolution issue on the DVI port for the GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti].
So now I am stuck with only the DVI-D port working correctly and there is no output on the HDMI port on on the Display Port.  When I plug in the other displays, they are not even recognized in the settings displays menu from the gear icon at top-right.
Software and Update result in the Nouveau display driver that is not installed and the 500 series drivers that break the resolution on the DVI port.

How can I get full resolution on the DVI port as well as getting output on the HDMI port and the DP (Display Port)?
